# sqlite: performance issue on select * from

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a large number of records of type `[crc INT, name VARCHAR]`

Some (few) of the `crc` records will be duplicates. I am interested in a fast way to select items that have a specific `crc` value.

Does it worth (in terms of performance) to make `crc` field `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (that is unique) and make `name` a compound value (it's doable but ugly - i think) or just create an index on `crc` field ?

Making the `crc` column `PRIMARY` will add significant performance ?

Can someone help ?

Comment: This is marked C++ why?

Comment: `sqlite` is also used in php and many other programming languages. I am only interested in C++.

Comment: If crc contains duplicate values, you can't make it the primary key.  Creating an index seems to be the way to go.

Comment: the option was: make crc primary, AND add all values to name: name will be for example: name1;name2;name3

Answer (score 0):

1) select items that have a specific crc value:
`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE crc=777;`

2)don't make the crc field as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, cause it may duplicate. You should better create the 'id' field that would be unique and mark it as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`

Answer (score 0):

Storing a list of names will create problem when you want to access individual names.
(But if you always look up or retrieve all those names at once, there will be not much of a problem.)

If there are duplicates, you cannot make that column the primary key.
Just creating a (non-unique) index is the simplest solution.

Using an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY index is a little bit more efficient that a separate index, but the difference is unlikely to be significant.

Comment: I know and agree everything you said. But the question is about performance. Making the `crc` column `PRIMARY` will add significant performance ?